# How to search through nested has_many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Here what I have now :

```
class Pokemon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pokemon_moves, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :moves, through: :pokemon_moves
end

class PokemonMove < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pokemon
  belongs_to :move
end

class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
end
```

And many others, no important.
I just would like to search for a Pokémon which could have Move named "pound" and another Move "mega-punch"

I tried :

```
Pokemon.joins(:moves).where(moves: {name: 'pound'}).where(moves: {name: 'mega-punch'})
```

But no result. The translated SQL is :

```
SELECT "pokemons".* FROM "pokemons" INNER JOIN "pokemon_moves" ON "pokemon_moves"."pokemon_id" = "pokemons"."id" INNER JOIN "moves" ON "moves"."id" = "pokemon_moves"."move_id" WHERE "moves"."name" = $1 AND "moves"."name" = $2  [["name", "pound"], ["name", "mega-punch"]]
```

If I only search for one move, it works just fine, but I can't get it with two moves.

I have tried many things, but all concludes to bad results.
Of course, I have a Pokémon that have those moves, if I do `Pokemon.find_by_name('golurk').moves` I can retrieve those two moves.

Thanks !

**UPDATE 1 :**
I made it work by simply using `&` operator :

```
Pokemon.joins(:moves).where(moves: {name: 'pound'}) & Pokemon.joins(:moves).where(moves: {name: 'mega-punch'})
```

But it's really not efficient, and I'm pretty sure we can find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get no results is because you are searching for moves with the name  `pound` AND the name `mega punch`.

Change your code to:

```
Pokemon.joins(:moves).where(moves: {name: ['pound', 'mega-punch']})
```

Chaining `where` results in `AND` in your sql. If you want `OR`, either use an array like in the example above, or write your own sql.

Comment: Your code does a OR request. I don't want to get a Pokémon that have "pound" OR "mega-punch", I want one that have "pound" AND "mega-punch". Thanks for your answer !